# Remote Playback Device

Tags: wireless, system, remote, recording

I am looking for a small device/system that I can pre record a one or two word message on and play it back with the push of a remote button. Ideally, the remote would have 3-5 buttons for different messages and it would be wireless. If it had to be wired, the wires would need to be about 4 feet long. Does a product like this exist? Any thoughts? I work with special needs students and am looking for a discrete device as opposed to a phone or tablet app. I'm thinking something similar to what goes into stuffed toys may be applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of these: -

[image]

Or one of these: -

[image]

Or this: -

[image]

Try googling "voice record and playback IC" and looking at the images. It's quite easy. I've used the device at the top BTW.

Answer (score 1):

There are extraordinarily inexpensive PC board products availabe on Ebay (etc.) which are audio players and built-in speaker amplifiers on a board hardly larger than a couple of postage stamps.  And typically less than $5, ready to plug in and go.  You can record the audio clip(s) onto a micro SDHC card on any computer and then just plug the card into the board.  Easily less expensive than actually building anything from scratch or a kit.

Here is just one current example (of many) on sale for US$1.79!

http://www.ebay.com/itm/MP3-Format-TF-Card-U-Disk-decoder-board-module-amplifier-decoding-audio-Player-/141927599236